# Wrong JDBC driver being used?

Tags: java, jdbc, postgresql-9.3

I have a method that inserts a record into a Postgres DB and returns the identity field generated for said record.  The problem is, if I include the Redshift driver in my POM file, that driver is getting used instead of the Postgres driver - and the Redshift driver doesn't allow returning the identity value.

The code is:

```
try {
  Class.forName( "org.postgresql.Driver" ).newInstance();
  Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/postgres", "postgres", "password" );
  Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
  stmt.execute( "insert into public.job ( job_name ) values ( 'test' )" , Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS );
  ResultSet keyset = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
  if ( keyset.next() ) System.out.println( keyset.getLong( 1 ) );
}
catch ( Exception e ) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When this POM is used, it works:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When this POM is used, it does not work:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>redshift.jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.0002</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What is making Java choose the Redshift driver rather than the Postgres driver?

(the Redshift driver's classpath is **com.amazon.jdbc41.Driver**, so I wouldn't think it's a classpath conflict)

TIA

Comment: If you don't want to use the Redshift driver, why are you including it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is, that Java supports the `ServiceLoader` mechanism with JDBC 4.0.

In JDBC 4, the `DriverManager` will find and register drivers from the `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` setting in their jar file. When you call `getConnection()` the DriverManager will choose the first suitable driver for the jdbc URL given.

Now redshift and postgres driver are different in terms of jdbc url, but (quoting from the redshift docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html#obtain-jdbc-url):

> A JDBC URL specified with the former format of jdbc:postgresql://endpoint:port/database will still work.

Now, what happens, is, that the JDBC driver from redshift is loaded over the service entry and places himself as the driver for the redshift jdbc URL and the postgres one.

I cannot tell exactly if the `DriverManager` allows overwriting existing jdbc-driver-links by loading another driver, but a solution to your problem could be the explicit control to either load the postgres driver first (if URL will be registered only once) or to explicitly load it after the redshift driver (if JDBC URL mapping can be overwritten).

I cannot tell, if there is a property to disallow the redshift driver to register for the postgres URL.

Comment: I have opened the drivers jar, at least for the current version, there is no package name clash. The JDBC URL clash is (I suppose) a "convenience" feature, just use the old URL, drop in the new jar and use the new driver. Otherwise I did not mean to judge here, as the OP did just ask why this happens.

Comment: Thanks thst for pointing me in the right direction.  The solution (so far) is to call DriverManager.deregisterDriver( <the RedshiftDriver> ).  Seems like a kludge, but until I find a better way, it gets me going again.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The only way I've been able to get the drivers to load consistently in the right order was to add:

```
static {
    // Put the redshift driver at the end so that it doesn't
    // conflict with postgres queries
    java.util.Enumeration<Driver> drivers =  DriverManager.getDrivers();
    while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
        Driver d = drivers.nextElement();
        if (d.getClass().getName().equals("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver")) {
            try {
                DriverManager.deregisterDriver(d);
                DriverManager.registerDriver(d);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not deregister redshift driver");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Which is pretty gross, but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

As commented below PGDatasource uses DriverManger too, but it is possible  directly create `org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection`:

```
Properties info = new Properties();
info.put("password", "postgres");
Jdbc4Connection c = new Jdbc4Connection(new HostSpec[]{new HostSpec("localhost", 5432)}, "postgres", "postgres", info, "");
```

Comment: We tried this, but the PGPoolingDataSource uses the DriverManager behind the scenes so the result is the same.

Comment: See https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/org/postgresql/ds/common/BaseDataSource.java#L84