# JDBC Advantage Database Not finding tables (Driver Conflict?)

Tags: java, database, jdbc, advantage-database-server

Ok, I believe that the problem is that I am not getting a proper connection to the database but I am not sure.

First of all I am connecting to the database:

```
Class.forName("com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSDriver");    
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:extendedsystems:advantage://*ip*\D:\*path*\db.add;User ID=*username*;Password=*password*;ServerType=REMOTE;"
```

Then I try to use the data:

```
statement = connection.createStatement();
results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [TABLE]");
```

...and I get the exception:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'TABLE'.
```

I know that [Table] exists so I finally try to do a test to see if I am in fact getting visibility of the tables that I am looking for. So I did this:

```
DatabaseMetaData dmd = cConnection.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = dmd.getTables(cConnection.getCatalog(), null, "TAB_%", null);
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
}
```

..and get this output:

```
TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
TABLE_PRIVILEGES
TABLES
table_types
tables
```

Which clearly looks like system tables, and does not contain any of the MANY tables I know to be in the database I am looking at.

This has led me to believe that maybe I am not properly connecting to the database.

This is what I know:

- [TABLE] exists in this database and that I have the exact name correct.
- The Data Dictionary is defiantly D:\*path*\db.add
- The database is located on a different server than I am running my code on. I refer to it by IP.
- I have tried adding port 6262, the default port for Advantage databases, to the connection string and this had no effect.
- I am certain I am getting the password and username correct, the account I am using does NOT have admin privileges though.
- (EDIT) The account DOES have FULL privileges over [TABLE].
- I am using the most recent JDBC driver available from Sybase.
- I made a system DSN on another machine using this path, data dictionary and credentials using Sybase's ODBC driver and was able to connect without an issue.
- (EDIT) [TABLE] is located inside the default schema in the database.

Thank you for any help you can offer, I am sure I am missing something small.

---

UPDATE: I updated the question title to better reflect the question now that I have located the source of my problem.

Credit to Luke Woodward in the comments below for helping me locate the source of my problem. I am still, however, having trouble finding a solution.

Earlier in the application I use

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

To establish a connection to a SQL Server 2008 database, this connection works fine.

It seems the error is occurring because the DriverManager is attempting to use the SQL driver instead of the Advantage driver for the second connection as well. This is causing it to not be able to read the tables properly. I was able to find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304195/wrong-jdbc-driver-being-used), but I am a little unsure how to adapt this solution to my problem.  The proposed solution to this question was to use `DriverManager.deregisterDriver()` to get the other driver out of my way.

So I borrowed this code from one of the answers to the above question:

```
java.util.Enumeration<Driver> drivers =  DriverManager.getDrivers();
while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
    Driver d = drivers.nextElement();
    if (d.getClass().getName().equals("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")) {
        try {
            DriverManager.deregisterDriver(d);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not deregister redshift driver");
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, for some reason the mere presence of this code in the application stops the first connection from being established, even though it is in a different class AND should be executed after the first connection is already established. As soon as I comment this out, the first connection works just fine again.

The purpose of this application is to pull data from source A, format it and add some bits, then move it into source B. Because of the processing I have to do I need to grab some data from A, do some stuff, then grab data from B, do some stuff, add some data to B, then add some data to A, so I have to have both connections open at the same time.

So this question has now become, how do I deal with this driver conflict so that I connect to both databases within the same application at the same time?

Comment: Does the username you are using have permission to view the table?

Comment: What schema does your table exist in?  What user are you logging in as?  You are likely missing the owner.  If HR is the schema -  Select * from HR.EMPLOYEES instead of Select * from EMPLOYEES.

Comment: The database is a fairly simple one (just with a lot of data) and was not built with multiple schema, so it is in the default schema. I am certain that the user I am using has permissions to view the table, as well as modify it. I use this user login all the time in Advantage Data Architect to view/modify tables.

Comment: I'm surprised to see a `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException` exception.  The Advantage driver JAR (adsjdbc.jar) doesn't contain any classes under `com.microsoft`. Are you using the MS SQL driver in your app as well?  Are you absolutely sure that you're using an Advantage connection, not a MS SQL connection, to talk to your Advantage database?

Comment: @Luke I had not noticed that before. I do use a separate connection to a SQL database in another part of the application. This may be causing a conflict in which it is pulling in the wrong driver. I will work on this and if that turns out to be the solution I will ask that you remake your comment as an answer so that I can give you credit. Thank you.

Comment: Having taken a look at both drivers I would expect them to interoperate: they don't share any classes and handle different database URLs.  When talking to your Advantage database, are you absolutely sure that the connection you think is to your Advantage database is actually your Advantage connection and not your MS SQL connection?  My concern is that you're doing something like passing the MS SQL connection to a method that expects the Advantage connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue and I honestly feel as if I wasted all of your time.

Credit to **Luke Woodward** for helping me find the solution.

When I built the classes that I use to connect to the two databases I knew that they would share many of the same functions so I built a parent class with those functions then extended the parent to the ADBConnection and the SQLConnection classes. When I did this though there were some variable issues that I had missed including one that included a static variable that messed everything up.  I was never connecting to the Advantage database at all, instead I was creating another SQL server connection and looking for a database that wasn't there. Not sure how this translated to being able to even see the system tables but that was the problem.

I have corrected the variable naming issues and am now properly creating a connection to both databases and getting data moving.

Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for you.

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/atm";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    return conn;
}
```

For more check my simple console based (still need to workout to complete) atm but connection is perfect in this project. Here is the link.
https://github.com/SaugatBhattarai/atm/blob/master/DbPreparedStatement.java

Comment: I appreciate your answer however, I fear this is not my solution.  The method that your using seems to rely on the connection string builder inside of DriverManager, other than that it seems to be much the same as what I am using.  I have tested doing it this way, just to be sure before I dismissed it, and got the same exception.  Your project worked with this code for MySQL it seems. From my observations SQL has slightly different rules than Advantage. This same project requires a connection to a SQL Server 2008 database and I am able to connect to it without issue.

Comment: This answer will not be remotely helpful to the questioner.  They have asked a question about Sybase SQLAdvantage, and what do you do?  You provide a generic code sample for connecting to MySQL.  In case you haven't realised it, that's a completely different database. -1