# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazon/redshift/core/jdbc41/PGJDBC41DriverImpl

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-redshift

I am upgrading Redshift driver to latest 1.2.10.1009 version. Previously, I have used version 1.2.1.1001.

Pom.xml entry

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
    <artifactId>redshift-jdbc41</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.10.1009</version>
</dependency>
```

After upgrade, the same code is throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazon/redshift/core/jdbc41/PGJDBC41DriverImpl

Stack trace:

```
2017-11-16T14:19:12.53+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2017-11-16 08:49:12.530 ERROR 11 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazon/redshift/core/jdbc41/PGJDBC41DriverImpl] with root cause
   2017-11-16T14:19:12.53+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
   2017-11-16T14:19:12.53+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:38) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.1.jar!/:na]
   2017-11-16T14:19:12.53+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.1.jar!/:na]
   2017-11-16T14:19:12.53+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.1.jar!/:na]
   2017-11-16T14:19:12.53+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-9.0.1.jar!/:na]
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you also using mysql in your jar? If yes, it will be replacing redshift in as jdbc driver.

Comment: See the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304195/wrong-jdbc-driver-being-used